# XrayImportBuilder adding new test cases to Test Execution instead of updating the existing test cases

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jira-xray, x-ray

We are using XrayImportBuilder to Import test results TestNg from our Jenkins job to Jira for the Automation .
The parameters are defined in the Jenkins File as below

```
stage('Import results to Xray') {
    steps {
        step([$class: 'XrayImportBuilder', 
               endpointName: '/testng', 
               importFilePath: 'target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml',     
                importToSameExecution: 'true', 
                serverInstance: 'ecc67055-c359-40cb-8b8a-a44cb9f6ca30'
                 testExecKey: 'CPT-123'])
    }
}
```

Until last week, the Jenkins jobs which ran 2 times a week, updated the Existing Test Cases in the Test Execution - CPT-123 with the results - PASS/FAIL.
However when the last Jenkins build that ran on Monday morning , new test cases were created , instead of the existing test cases being updated.
This is causing duplicate test cases being created.
No changed have been made in the Automation code , nothing new was pushed since last 3 months .

Any inputs highly appreciated

I was expecting that the existing test cases be updated in the test execution - CPT-123 , but instead it created additional test cases and added to the Test execution

Comment: Are you using a cloud instance of Jira or a Server/DC instance? Do you have changed the TestNG version between uploads? On the snippet provided you are missing a comma after the 'serverInstance' entry, make sure it is there or the next parameter will not be accounted for. Last verification is compare the field 'Description' of the old and new Generic Test created to see what has changed.

Comment: Thanks Cristiano.I am using a cloud instance . No changes were made , on POM or Code changes . Let me have a look at the description

Comment: The field description is exactly the same

Comment: Last verification is on the snippet provided, from the Jenkinsfile, you are missing a comma after the 'serverInstance: 'ecc67055-c359-40cb-8b8a-a44cb9f6ca30'' entry, make sure it is there or the next parameter will not be accounted for.